# how to fetch chat message data from firebase those timestamp greater saved time stamp?

Tags: android

how to fetch chat message data from firebase those timestamp greater than saved last msg timestamp?
i have save last message time stamp when i press back button
now i have to fetch those messages only whose timestamp grater than saved tiemstamp.
i have save last message time stamp when i press back button
now i have to fetch those messages only whose timestamp grater than saved tiemstamp.
please tell me any query for that or  any other solution.
[image: firebase database model]

Comment: check you api documentation. You should see and endpoint with some params about timestamp.

If not, you will have to fetch everything and check in your android app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase doc. state the following:

> `orderByChild()`    Order results by the **value** of a specified child key.

Also

> `startAt()`       Return items greater than or equal to the specified key or **value** depending on the order-by method chosen.

Therefore you can achieve the ordering by using this line

```
dataBaseRef.child("messages").orderByChild("timestamp").startAt(savedTimeStamp)
```

Hope it helps.